# Playframework(scala)のActionを記載はどのようなScalaの構文から成り立っているのでしょうか？

Tags: scala, playframework

Playframework(scala)を学習しています。Javaは一通り理解しているつもりなのですがScalaの構文が難しくて苦戦しています。質問内容はPlayframeworkのActionを記述する構文はどのようなScalaの構文で記載しているのか教えてほしいです。冗長でも分解してどういう構文で記載されているのか教えてほしいです。

こちらの文書によると、

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/ja/2.4.x/ScalaActions

> 基本的に play.api.mvc.Action は、リクエストを処理してクライアントへ送るレスポンスを生成する (play.api.mvc.Request => play.api.mvc.Result) 型の関数です。

```
val echo = Action { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

とあります。OkはResult型を返す関数なので、

```
val echo = (request:Request) => Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
```

のような書き方でもいいんじゃないかと思いました。

`Action {}`というので囲むブロックがどういう構文で成り立っているのかわかりません。
この記述のしかたはScalaのどういう構文で記述されているのか教えてほしいです。

Comment: [PlayframeworkのActionからscala文法を紐解く](https://qiita.com/NewGyu/items/e5dce51c4cfd6133c7b0)

Comment: ありがとうございます。記載された記事の内容はまだ理解できないてすが、この先調べていくキーワードがいくつか知ることが出来たので引き続き調べていきます